# Exact Broadcom B43 driver

Tags: optimization, linux-device-driver, firmware, broadcom

This might be a stupid question but here we go.
My laptop has a Broadcom wifi card, the exact info being:

```
    Slot:   06:00.0
    Class:  Network controller [0280]
    Vendor: Broadcom Limited [14e4]
    Device: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [4311]
    SVendor:    Hewlett-Packard Company [103c]
    SDevice:    BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [1364]
    Rev:    01
```

It works with the B43 driver.
However, when I open the /lib/firmware/b43 directory there is a long list of files like:

```
    0g0bsinitvals5.fw lcn1initvals25.fw n0bsinitvals25.fw ucode14.fw
    a0g0bsinitvals9.fw lcn1initvals26.fw n0initvals11.fw ucode15.fw
    a0g0initvals5.fw lcn2bsinitvals24.fw n0initvals16.fw ucode16_lp.fw
    a0g0initvals9.fw lcn2bsinitvals25.fw n0initvals17.fw ucode16_mimo.fw
    a0g1bsinitvals13.fw lcn2bsinitvals26.fw n0initvals22.fw ucode16_sslpn.fw
    a0g1bsinitvals5.fw lcn2initvals24.fw n0initvals24.fw ucode16_sslpn_nobt.fw
```

I just posted a few lines, repeat it's a long list.

My question is twofold.
A) What do all these files mean?
B) Do I need them all or, knowing exactly the driver on my machine as listed above, is there a way to identify those few files I truly need and erase all the others?

Comment: A) all those are firmware files. B1) no, you don't need all of them. B2) yes. B3) if you are using distro, the deletion of unused files will corrupt internal state of package manager, thus don't do this if you have no clear understanding.

Comment: Thanks, for the input. Actually I didn't installed the driver with a package manager, just copied the b43 folder which i use for different distro. How would I identify which among those files correspond to the card in use (except trial and error of course.)? Also, they come in combinations of 4 for each line, is that the way they work?